# Connecting to SQL server over the internet

Tags: sql-server, sql, deployment

One of my clients has a db that contains their data (this server also host an ASP.NET webshop) and they had me write a program for their client which with they can query their db. My problem is that i was advised not to make the SQL server accessible directly through the internet? What would be the standard practice? Should I deploy a VPN client automatically? Im kinda confused on this one. Please advise.

Comment: Whether or not the SQL server is accessible directly from the internet is kind of out of your hands and in the hands of the person who manages the router/firewall at the perimeter of the network that the SQL server is behind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The standard practice is to not do it.

Either use a VPN / DirectAccess, or use a web service interface.

Comment: yes, that was my initial idea too, but is there a way to deploy a VPN client with the installer of my app? I was thinking about openVPN, but couldn't find anything on how to do that.

Comment: Ok, the next one who does not know Windows? Windows HAS INCLUDED CLIENTS for PPTP, IPSEC. Newer Versions even Support other Standards, including MS popietary DirectAccess. There is ZERO Need to deploy a Client if the admin had a clue selecting a VPN Technology.

Comment: @Andris - The problem with deploying a VPN client with your program is that there has to be a VPN server on the other end. Who's going to install, configure and maintain that? What about when network changes require a VPN server and/or client change? This sounds like an untenable solution.

Comment: @TomTom, i knew about directaccess, but i think its only available on 7 or higher.

Comment: @joeqwerty Then Web Service Interface it is, right?

Comment: @Andris pretty much. Program a decent Interface.

Comment: @TomTom, Will try, will do. Thanks. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

Between two servers - certificate-based encryption.

Encrypting Connections to SQL Server
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189067%28v=sql.105%29.aspx